# How to return a value from a function of type `LPCTSTR`?

Tags: c++, winapi

What is the 'proper' way to return `wintitle` from the function?

The way i did the compiler is pointing this warning: `warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary: wintitle`

```
LPCTSTR WinGetTitle(HWND hWnd)
{
    TCHAR wintitle[250];
    GetWindowText(hWnd, wintitle, GetWindowTextLength(hWnd) + 1);
    return wintitle;
}

LPCTSTR wintitle;    
wintitle = WinGetTitle(hWnd);
```

Comment: Why not use reference instead? `WinGetTitle(HWND hwnd, LPCTSTR& win_title)...`

Comment: @Asesh `void WinGetTitle(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR &wintitle) { GetWindowText(hWnd, wintitle, GetWindowTextLength(hWnd) + 1); }`? `argument of type "LPCTSTR" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR"`

Comment: Then you should replace `LPCTSTR` with `LPCWSTR`. Looks you are using wide-character encoding. `LPCTSTR` is pointer to char: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/f8d4fe46-6be8-44c9-8823-615a21d17a61

Comment: Theres another way than passing the value as reference?

Comment: Return a `std::wstring`. You can use `GetWindowTextLength` first, then resize the string and pass its buffer directly to `GetWindowText`. This avoids the potential buffer overflow in the given example if the window text was longer than 250 characters. If you are actually using `TCHAR` for its intended purpose of being able to easily switch between Unicode and Multi-Byte then this requires a bit more thought. If you're only using it because you saw it in a Microsoft example do yourself a favor and just use real types.

Comment: @Nathan Maybe use `using TCharArray = std::basic_string<TCHAR>;` and use `TCharArray` instead of `LPCTSTR`?  Of course you do as suggested by RetiredNinja, but at least you have the flexibility of the string being compatible between Unicode and Multibyte.

Comment: LPCTSTR is a pointer and returning a pointer is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: @paul We don't need to worry about Windows 98 anymore. We can just use wstring

Comment: @Asesh That's just the worst of all worlds combined. You're suggesting to pass a reference to a pointer. What this necessitates is that the function now allocate memory, fill it, and assign it to the client-provided reference. The client now has a raw pointer they're responsible for, and no way of knowing, *how* they would need to free it (`free()`? `delete[]`? `CoTaskMemFree()`? something else?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler diagnostic is spot on: `wintitle` is an object with automatic storage duration. When the function returns, it's memory is automatically freed, leaving the returned pointer dangling.

If you *do* wish (you probably don't) to return a pointer, you'll have to have it point into memory that outlives the function call. That's either a pointer into a buffer with static storage duration, or a heap allocation. Neither is particularly useful (the former needs to be fixed size, and the latter puts the burden of releasing the memory on the caller, which usually doesn't know how to).

It is far more practical to return an object that manages its memory automatically. Using a [`std::wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is the canonical solution. You can instantiate an object, fill it with contents, and then return it to the caller:

```cpp
std::wstring WinGetTitle(HWND hWnd)
{
    std::wstring wintitle;
    auto const len = ::GetWindowTextLengthW(hWnd);
    if (len > 0) {
        wintitle.resize(static_cast<size_t>(len));
        GetWindowTextW(hWnd, wintitle.data(), len + 1);
    }
    return wintitle;
}
```

If you need to get an `LPCWSTR` pointer to pass it into other API calls, you can use `std::wstring`'s [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) member.

This requires C++17 to return a pointer to non-const from `data()`. Also note that I omitted using [generic-text mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/generic-text-mappings). Those aren't useful, unless you're targeting Win9x (which has been out of support for a while now).